# My php Score does not increment

Tags: php

I have a simple procedural card game I've been making, everything seems to be working fine except my Score at best.

I can get the score to adjust itself and increment by 1 but when the player gets 2 consecutive correct answers the score remains at 1.

```
<body>
    <form action=Cardgame.php method="get">
        <button name="Higher" type="submit" value="submit">Higher</button>
        <button name="Lower" type="submit" value="submit">Lower</button>
        <button name="NewDeal" type="submit" value="submit">NewDeal?</button>
    </form>
</body>
<?php
    $Cards = array(
        1 => '2 of Clubs',
        2 => '2 of Diamonds',
        3 => '2 of Hearts',
        4=>'2 of spades',
        5=>'3 of Clubs',
        6=>'3 of Diamonds',
        7=>'3 of Hearts',
        8=>'3 of spades',
        9=>'4 of Clubs',
        10=>'4 of Diamonds',
        11=>'4 of Hearts',
        12=>'4 of spades',
        13=>'5 of Clubs',
        14=>'5 of Diamonds',
        15=>'5 of Hearts',
        16=>'5 of spades',
        17=>'6 of Clubs',
        18=>'6 of Diamonds',
        19=>'6 of Hearts',
        20=>'6 of spades',
        21=>'7 of Clubs',
        22=>'7 of Diamonds',
        23=>'7 of Hearts',
        24=>'7 of spades',
        25=>'8 of Clubs',
        26=>'8 of Diamonds',
        27=>'8 of Hearts',
        28=>'6 of spades',
        29=>'9 of Clubs',
        30=>'9 of Diamonds',
        31=>'9 of Hearts',
        32=>'6 of spades',
        33=>'10 of Clubs',
        34=>'10 of Diamonds',
        35=>'10 of Hearts',
        36=>'10 of spades',
        37=>'J of Clubs',
        38=>'J of Diamonds',
        39=>'J of Hearts',
        40=>'J of spades',
        41=>'Q of Clubs',
        42=>'Q of Diamonds',
        43=>'Q of Hearts',
        44=>'Q of spades',
        45=>'K of Clubs',
        46=>'K of Diamonds',
        47=>'K of Hearts',
        48=>'K of spades',
        49=>'A of Clubs',
        50=>'A of Diamonds',
        51=>'A of Hearts',
        52=>'A of spades'
    );
    $Score= 0;
    $PlayerCard = rand (1,52);
    $Cardrand = rand (1,52);
    if ($PlayerCard==$Cardrand) {
        $Cardrand = rand (1,52);
    }
    echo $Cards[$PlayerCard] . $Cards[$Cardrand];
    if (isset($_GET['Higher'])) {
        if ($PlayerCard>$Cardrand) {
            ++$Score ;
        }
        else {
            $Score = 0;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['Lower'])) {
        if ($PlayerCard<$Cardrand){
            ++$Score ;
        }
        else {
            $Score = 0;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['NewDeal'])) {
        $Score=0;
        $PlayerCard = rand (0,51);
        $Cardrand = rand (0,51);
    }
    echo $Score;
?>
```

I have tried the $variable++ ++$Variable, I keep trying different ways but still can't get the counter to increment by more than 1.

Please help....

Comment: did you try $Score+=1; ?
also score =0 ; it come back to 0 each time page refresh i think shall session

Comment: yes I'm afraid so with the same outcome

Comment: change this condition `if ($PlayerCard>$Cardrand) {` to `if ($PlayerCard>=$Cardrand) {`

Comment: changed it, no change to score unfortunately

Comment: did you try session  or cookies  for me it really look you refresh page on each request $Score become back to 0 again

Comment: I think it could possibly be I'm defining the variable in the wrong place, what i think is going on is that the page keeps refreshing to 0 after each input meaning that the score wont ever go above 1. any suggestions where i should define this variable i have already tried inside my if statement, or is my diagnosis completely off?

Comment: yes Jehad i have also come to this conclusion! you say session cookies is the area i should be looking into.

Comment: Thankyou for the help Jehad i think you have cracked my problem, I'm going to do abit of research into session cookies and see if this was the missing piece to my puzzle. Thankyou very much

Comment: i make you simple answer you can improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting $score to be 0 everytime you refresh the page.

That is the reason doing $score++ only adds 1.

The code is read from top to bottom. What is one of the first things happening? - You are setting $score to be 0. Then you are later adding 1 to that score doing $score++;

The only way to achieve this is setting the score variable in a Session (recommended) or a cookie or file or something that keeps the value of the variable even if you refresh the page.

Here is a quick example:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}

if (isset($_GET['Higher'])) {
    if ($PlayerCard > $Cardrand) {
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Sourcey, after abit of troubleshooting I fully agree, Thankyou for this piece of code I do appreciate your help! I will give it a go and look into sessions and cookies in more detail. Very helpful!!

Comment: No problem. Please click accept my answer if it satisfied your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

if i unerstand your game correct shall be some thing like this

```
    <form action="/testphp" method="get">
    <button name="Higher" type="submit" value="submit">Higher</button>
     <button name="Lower" type="submit" value="submit">Lower</button>
    <button name="NewDeal" type="submit" value="submit">NewDeal?</button>
    </form>
    </body>


    <?php



    $Cards = array(
     1=>'2 of Clubs' ,2=>'2 of Diamonds',3=>'2 of Hearts',4=>'2 of spades',
    5=>'3 of Clubs',6=>'3 of Diamonds',7=>'3 of Hearts',8=>'3 of spades',
    9=>'4 of Clubs',10=>'4 of Diamonds',11=>'4 of Hearts',12=>'4 of spades',
    13=>'5 of Clubs',14=>'5 of Diamonds',15=>'5 of Hearts',16=>'5 of spades',
    17=>'6 of Clubs',18=>'6 of Diamonds',19=>'6 of Hearts',20=>'6 of spades',
    21=>'7 of Clubs',22=>'7 of Diamonds',23=>'7 of Hearts',24=>'7 of spades',
    25=>'8 of Clubs',26=>'8 of Diamonds',27=>'8 of Hearts',28=>'6 of spades',
    29=>'9 of Clubs',30=>'9 of Diamonds',31=>'9 of Hearts',32=>'6 of spades',
    33=>'10 of Clubs',34=>'10 of Diamonds',35=>'10 of Hearts',36=>'10 of spades',
    37=>'J of Clubs',38=>'J of Diamonds',39=>'J of Hearts',40=>'J of spades',
    41=>'Q of Clubs',42=>'Q of Diamonds',43=>'Q of Hearts',44=>'Q of spades',
    45=>'K of Clubs',46=>'K of Diamonds',47=>'K of Hearts',48=>'K of spades',
    49=>'A of Clubs',50=>'A of Diamonds',51=>'A of Hearts',52=>'A of spades',);


    session_start();
    if (!empty($_SESSION['Score'])) {
    $Score =   $_SESSION['Score']  ;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['Score'] = 0 ;
      $Score= 0;
    }

  $PlayerCard = rand (1,52);
  $Cardrand = rand (1,52);

  if ($PlayerCard==$Cardrand) {
    $Cardrand = rand (1,52);
    }
   echo $Cards[$PlayerCard] . $Cards[$Cardrand];




  if (isset($_GET['Higher'])) {
  if ($PlayerCard>$Cardrand) {

   ++$Score ;

  }
    else {
     $Score--;

  }
  $_SESSION['Score'] = $Score;
  }



   if (isset($_GET['Lower'])) {
   if ($PlayerCard<$Cardrand){

    ++$Score ;

    }
    else {
    $Score--;

     }
     $_SESSION['Score'] = $Score;
   }


  if (isset($_GET['NewDeal'])) {

  $Score=0;
  $PlayerCard = rand (0,51);
  $Cardrand = rand (0,51);
  $_SESSION['Score'] = $Score;
   }



   echo "<br><strong>" .$_SESSION['Score']."</strong>";

  ?>
```

Comment: This worked beautifully Jehad, I really do appreciate you taking time out your day to support a learner. Past experience with the site makes me hesitate using it but the help today has restored my confidence in it. Couldnt be more grateful for your help